# select distinct columns from db2 table

Tags: sql, spring, db2, spring-batch, batch-processing

I'm using spring batch to read from table and write the data to another table and I'm using spring writer for the insertion part. My problem is:

I'm getting data from a table that looks like the following:

```
cust   type   date
====   =====  ====
 1       P    1985
 1       P    1980
 1       P    1970
 2       P    1984
```

and I'm trying to insert these data to another table by running a query that `select distinct( cust , type)` from the above table to get the following result:

```
cust   type   date
====   =====  ====
 1       P    1985
 2       P    1984
```

so basically what I want to do is to get the distinct set of `cust and type` and if there are multiple records for this `cust. type` set then I get the `max(date)`.

Is there anyway to do so in using query? or any recommendation for an efficient approach?

Thanks in advance!

> UPDATE:

there are some records in date that have NULL value so for example

```
cust   type   date
====   =====  ====
 1       P    NULL
 1       P    NULL
 1       P    NULL
 2       P    1984
```

and if I query for `max(date)` it will not return back any record from `cust(1)` .. any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Just use `group by`...

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   cust, 
   type, 
   max(isnull(date,'1/jan/1900')) 
from 
   <table>
group by 
    cust, 
    type
```

Should do the job!

EDIT:

Added in an isnull around the date, so that if it is null it will still return a value. I haven't tested it myself, so let me know how it goes!

Comment: thanks @LordBaconPants for your reply! I used and its working except for one scenario that I didn't mention in my question please check the update of the question. hope u can help me with it